# Accessing properties file in Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created a simple web application with Thymeleaf using Spring Boot. I use the application.properties file as configuration. What I'd like to do is add new properties such as name and version to that file and access the values from Thymeleaf.

I have been able to achieve this by creating a new JavaConfiguration class and exposing a Spring Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    @Bean
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I can then display it in a template using Thymeleaf like so:

```
<span th:text="${@name}"></span>
```

This seems overly verbose and complicated to me. What would be a more elegant way of achieving this?

If possible, I'd like to avoid using xml configuration.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get it via the `Environment`.  E.g.:

```
${@environment.getProperty('name')}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as '${name}'?

Comment: @DaveSyer no, this is not working for me in `th:text="${name}"`

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I tried to use ${name} orginally, but couldn't get that to work either. Any idea as to why it works in @Value though?

Comment: In `@Value` it should always work - that's the whole point. I guess the '${}' placeholders mean something different in Thymeleaf (makes sense they would be model attributes).

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple to do this in JavaConfig. Here's an example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
public class JavaConfigClass{

    @Value("${propertyName}")
    String name;


    @Bean //This is required to be able to access the property file parameters
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this is the XML equivalent:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
         <value>my.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Finally, you can use the Environment variable, but it's a lot of extra code for no reason.