# thymeleaf inline raw i18n message into javascript

Tags: jersey, thymeleaf

I've got messages .properties file containing that line:

```
BROWSER.MESSAGES={\r\n  "W_MH_B_TITLE" \: "Hello World"\r\n}
```

I try to inline it in the page as

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var i18nMessages = /*[(#{BROWSER.MESSAGES})]*/{};
</script>
```

As a result I get

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
  "W_MH_B_TITLE" : "Hello World"
"

My intention is to simply copy the value to javascipr. Without any sort of formatting.

Thymeleaf 3.0, **without** Spring

UPDATE: 
I workarounded that issue by customizing StandardMessageResolver (I have same key in every template):

```
// Once the messages map has been retrieved, just use it         
final String message = messagesForLocaleForTemplate.get(key);    
if (message != null) {                                           
    if("BROWSER.MESSAGES".equals(key)) {                         
        return message;                                          
    } else {                                                     
        return formatMessage(locale, message, messageParameters);
    }                                                            
}                                                                

// Will try the next resolver (if any)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing properties file in Spring Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610030/accessing-properties-file-in-spring-expression-language)

Comment: Sorry, no spring in my case. Jersey + thymeleaf

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the customization you mention in your update. Would it be possible to post that as an answer? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Thymeleaf 3 non-Spring solution:

Change your properties file entry to this (put the message in single quotes):

```
BROWSER.MESSAGES='{\r\n  "W_MH_B_TITLE" \: "Hello World"\r\n}'
```

This generates the following:

```
<script>
  var i18nMessages = {
    "W_MH_B_TITLE" : "Hello World"
  };
</script>
```

Comment: That will probably work. Though, this is more like a workaround. For mass usage will make other kind of problems like escaping single quotes.